# How to iterate through the names of all the users from the webpage using Python and Selenium

Tags: python, list, selenium, xpath

I am new to coding and need someone to hold my hand please...I am trying to create a bot that will use the nextdoor website to look for posts and send promotions to users through their messaging system.
So far I have been able to perform login, search, and navigate to the Posts tab. After this point is where I am stuck. I will post a picture and also my code so you can see the issue.
basically once I navigate to the posts tab, some posts appear from different users. I checked the html and looks like they have same div class. How do I make selenium check each users post. So far I am only able to find info on the first one and after that my code ends. I think I am having an iteration issue. Please help.

```
import sys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

PATH =Service("C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=PATH)

driver.get("https://nextdoor.com/news_feed/")
print(driver.title)
#driver.quit()
time.sleep(3)

#Finds username and password id's and logs into web page
search = driver.find_element(By.ID, "id_email")
search.send_keys("private")
search = driver.find_element(By.ID, "id_password")
search.send_keys("private")
search = driver.find_element(By.ID, "signin_button").click()
time.sleep(3)

#In the next section of code we will execute searches
search = driver.find_element(By.ID, "search-input-field")
search.send_keys("remodel")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(3)
#This section will locate posts tab and click on it
search = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"(//a[normalize-space()='Posts'])[1]").click()
time.sleep(2)
#This section will delete what was typed in the search bar
delete_search = driver.find_element(By.ID, "search-input-field")
delete_search.clear()
time.sleep(2)

for person in driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "css-15luflj"):
    title = person.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//span[@data-testid='styled-text'] 
[normalize-space()='Miguel Med'])[1]").text

    persons.append({'username': title})


print(persons)
```

Page screenshot:

[image]

Element screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @CarlosM239 At which line are you exactly stuck? Can you share with us a set of demo credentials to construct & test our solution for you?

Answer (score 0):

As you are able to able to find info on the first one presumably the [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver) are almost correct. You just need to modify the locator from *specific* to *generic*.

---

### Solution

Rather looking out for the specific user ***Miguel Med*** as:

```
title = person.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//span[@data-testid='styled-text'][normalize-space()='Miguel Med'])[1]").text
```

Collect for all the users as:

```
title = person.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//span[@data-testid='styled-text'][text()])[1]").text
```